# iOS native alert

Tags: ios, selenium, mobile-safari, native

Currently automating iOS Web app using selenium appium stack in iOS10.3, native app alert "This site is attempting to open popup window". Not able to switch the alert as we need to access the native layer from web layer. do looking forward for solution

Answer (score 2):

Try changing Appium context by:

```
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
```

Comment: @LongNguyen after performing the driver.context("NATIVE_APP");, how did you managed to click the 'Allow' button?

Comment: @Renjith driver.findElement(By.id("Allow")).click(); is working for me.

Comment: @LongNguyen. Thank you. I actually got it working with XPATH @label="Allow".